# How do i transform a user id into a new identification value, using across/apply function?

Tags: r, apply, across

I have a variable called user_id in a string format, like:
u:fwHX
u:fwHX
u:fwHX
u:h_lx
u:x_hi
u:x_hi

They all start with a "u:" and then followed by a set of letters. I want to transform each unique user_id into a string in the following format:

user_id    user_id
u:fwHX    U1
u:fwHX    U1
u:fwHX    U1
u:h_lx    U2
u:x_hi    U3
u:x_hi    U3

This new user_id variable can only go from U1 until U123 (e.g U321, U312,U123.....). And i have to use the across and apply function to solve it.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to convert the 'user_id' to index based on `unique` values and then `paste` the 'U' as prefix

```
df1$user_id_new <- with(df1, paste0("U", match(user_id, unique(user_id))))
```